# typeconverter from dll

Tags: c#, propertygrid, typeconverter

I am using the propertygrid with a class and associated type converter. 
When I moved the class and the TypeConverter to a dll, it seems that it is not being called.
Can't find how to activate the typeconverter from a dll.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(modulepath + elementname + ".dll");
try
{
    object myobj = a.CreateInstance(objectname);            
    Type objecttype = myobj.GetType();
}
```

Appreciate any hints. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because Assembly.LoadFile loads the file in a different [binding context](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx) from the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks erikkallen.
This pointed me to the right direction.
I found the solution here

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/22/SolvingTheAssemblyLoadContextProblem.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Do you have something like this in place on your class:

```
   [TypeConverter(typeof(MyClassConverter))]
 public class MyClass {
    // Insert code here.
 }
```

Usually as long as the class has the typeconverter associated with it it should pick it up.